# how set AWS global sdk configuration in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, amazon-javascript-sdk

I'm building a Vue SPA, that connects with some AWS services in the backend, and I need to globally configure the AWS SDK using a region and some credentials provided via STS. The problem is that after I call AWS.config.update inside my getCredentials submodule, the configuration doesn't update those parameters for subsequent imports of the SDK at different submodules.

The code looks like this:

getCredentials:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk/global';

AWS.config.update({
    region: 'aws-region',
    credentials: new myCredentialsObject(),
})
```

otherSubmodule:

```
const AWS = require('aws-skd');
const lambda = new AWS.Lamda();

lambda.invoke(params, callback);
```

The error I get back in the callback is:

```
ConfigError: Missing region in config
    at Request.VALIDATE_REGION (event_listeners.js?b7ab:94)
    at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js?78b0:106)
    at callNextListener (sequential_executor.js?78b0:96)
    at eval (event_listeners.js?b7ab:86)
    at finish (config.js?6e76:386)
    at Config.getCredentials (config.js?6e76:431)
    at Request.VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS (event_listeners.js?b7ab:81)
    at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js?78b0:102)
    at Request.emit (sequential_executor.js?78b0:78)
    at Request.emit (request.js?87f7:688)
```